# Applying union and power set in different orders.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Show that $E$ is always equal to $ \bigcup\{x:x\in \mathcal{P}(E)\} $ but that the result of applying $\mathcal{P}$ and $\bigcup$ to $E$ in the other order is a set that includes $E$ as a subset, typically a proper subset.

I don't understand the question from "but that the result..." onwards.

Comment: The second part of this question is not correct. $E\in\mathcal{P}(\cup E)$, not $E\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\cup E)$

Comment: The question is from Naive Set Theory by Halmos for future reference.

Comment: @DamjanBabić You should say something to clarify the situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says that $\mathcal{P}(\bigcup\, E)$ is not $E$ but (probably) a  bigger one. I mean

$$E\subset \mathcal{P}\left(\bigcup\, E\right)$$

You can see that $\bigcup\{x:x\in\mathcal{P}(E)\}=\bigcup\mathcal{P}(E)$.

EDIT: I am using this definition of union

$$x\in \bigcup E \leftrightarrow (\exists y\in E) (x\in y)$$

Comment: $E$ is not a subset of the power set of the trivial Union of $E$. It is an element of the power set.

Comment: No, it is not. If you take $\bigcup\, E$ then you get all the elements that are in each $x$ belonging to $E$ then $\mathcal{P}\left(\bigcup\, E \right)$ has in particular every element of $E$ but you can form (probably) other set that are not in $E$.

Comment: you are assuming that $E$ is a set of sets and that $\bigcup E=\bigcup_{X\in E} X$. If that is what the original problem meant, then you at right, but this notation is quite different than anything I have ever seen. Without these assumptions, your conclusion is incorrect.

Comment: What is the meaning you are given to the symbol $\bigcup$? I is weird you have never seen that notation before, it is used in Tomas Jech and Enderton's book about elementary set theory.

Comment: if those are the assumptions you are working under, you should add that information to your answer for clarity.

Comment: $\bigcup$ is shorthand for a repeated Union of the sets described on the mainline right after the symbol. For example $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ is shorthand for $A_1\cup A_2\cup ...\cup A_n$.

Comment: And in context? How do you apply $\bigcup$ to $E$.

Comment: since it is not indexed, $\bigcup E$ is the Union of a single set, namely $E$. Trivially $\bigcup E= E$.

Comment: What is a set of sets? I've managed to find this:
"we assume nevertheless (in this section only) that all the sets to be mentioned are subsets of one and the same set $E$ and that all complements (unless otherwise specified) are formed relative to that $E$."

Comment: A set of sets is a set who has sets. It is like a bag with bags inside.

Comment: Well then $E$ is a set of sets. Does this serve as a clarification to you? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: If I am taking the correct context all you have in the book you are using is a set, there is no more, every element, every number, every thing in that theory is a set. Then every set is essentially a set of sets.